# how to fix' no module name: object_objection.box_coders'?

Tags: python

ModuleNotFoundError on [object-detection](https://pypi.org/project/object-detection/)

> Error StackTrace

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 58, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import box_coder_builder
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\builders\box_coder_builder.py", line 17, in <module>
    from object_detection.box_coders import faster_rcnn_box_coder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection.box_coders'
```

Comment: Please post your code along with the error. It will help people to track down the bug in your code.

Comment: See this guide to create an env for Python 3.5: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your package is broken. Try reinstall it:

```
pip install --force-reinstall object-detection
```

---

Also see the docs's requires:

```
Requires: Python >=3.5, !=3.7.*
```

It only works with Python>=3.5 but no Python 3.7.*, so it doesn't work with your current Python. Consider install Python 3.5 and it should e fine.

Comment: its not working for me

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement object-detection (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for object-detection"

Comment: @GilbertChristianGraciano It's not helpful by simply stating "it's not working". What do you get? Any exception? Give me your code?

Comment: i get this notification when i try to reinstall it " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement object-detection (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for object-detection"

Comment: @GilbertChristianGraciano `pip --version` and `python --version` please.

Comment: pip -- version
python 3.7
python --version
Python 3.7.3

Comment: @GilbertChristianGraciano As the doc says, it requires any Python >=3.5 but **not** Python 3.7.* so it can't work with your current Python.

Comment: thanks mate for your solution. i reinstall the tensorflow(3.5 >=) but still get a same error. but i solved it, the problem only in the box_coder folder.

Comment: @GilbertChristianGraciano I wasn't talking about `tensorflow`! I talked about `Python` version! The best solution should be you create a virtual env for Python 3.5 and install required packages then. https://virtualenv.pypa.io